# How to make VS show ToString() value for classes inherited from List under debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When I create a class and override `ToString()`, and when I run Visual Studio under Debugger I can hover over the variable of the type with a mouse cursor and VS shows me whatever I return in the method, letting to put there sum of information typical for this particular class and valuable during debugging. However if I inherit my class from `List`, VS always shows something like `Count=20` ignoring value returned from my overridden `ToString()`, so I have to type `variable.ToString()` in QuickWatch window every time I want to see the class summary. Is there any way to make VS show `ToString()` for class inherited from `List`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your own sub-class that inherits the .NET `List` class, and override the `ToString()` method there. Anywhere you use the standard `List<type>` syntax would need to be changed to use your new custom List class.

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (T t in this)
        {
            sb.Append("[" + t.ToString() + "] ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyList<string> strings = new MyList<string>();
    strings.Add("asdf");
    strings.Add("teare");
}
```

generates this output when ToString() is called:

```
[asdf] [teare]
```

edit for your question:

i'd recommend building a common interface, and you can specify a particular template to match that version of whatever your list class is, that could then fetch specific custom class members. the code below demonstrates.

```
public interface IWidget
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Widget : IWidget
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Widget(string name_) { Name = name_; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{this.ToString()}")]
public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : IWidget
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (IWidget w in this)
        {
            sb.Append("[" + w.Name + "] ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note: this will limit the types that you can use in your custom collection class, but that might not matter depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, but I need to operate by this specific type's properties inside `ToString()`, so this method should be aware of type. `MyList<T>: List<T>`, and then `MySpecifiTypeList: MyList<MySpecificType>` does not help me, same Count = 20 as result

Comment: Mike, did you run it to check results? I copy&pasted your code, but keep getting Count=2. Please advise

Comment: yes, I tested all of this code in a test project before putting any of it up. post your working example in a SSCCE and I can see what's up.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same code you provided, copied it and pasted as is, and get the same Count=2. Note I'm talking about hovering mouse over `strings` variable, it does not run ToString() in my case

Comment: man, you're making me work here :)  it looks like when you hover over an object when execution is broken, VS doesn't call ToString() on the object. You can fix this by setting the 'debugger display' attribute. i've updated the code to show you how to do that. now, everything should work the way you want it to.